# Javascript wrong calculation

Tags: javascript

I have just tried a very simple calculation on javascript like this:
8.87 + 7.1, but the output is so unpredictable: 15.969999999999999 
Can anyone explain why ? And how to prevent this ?
I am using Chrome to execute the calculcation

Answer (score 1):

Binary numbers can not store floating point values 100% accurate. For this reason, inaccuracies like yours occur. Have a look at the following references:

[Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

[What causes floating point rounding errors?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors)

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

Float calculation is precision than integer. It has some error. The best way to prevent it is not using float.